# How to mass produce entry box widgets in Tkinter?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I would like to turn the following 4 lines of code into 1 line by calling a function or class. This way, i can just call the function for each entry box widget i want to create:

```
self.systest = StringVar()
self.systest.set("N/A")
self.e = Entry(self.frame1, textvariable=self.systest)
self.e.grid(row=6, column=1)
```

here is the function i am trying to create (doesn't actually work):

```
def entry_boxes(self, row, col, default, var, frame):
    setattr(self, var, StringVar)
    setattr(self, var, default)
    e = Entry(frame, textvariable=var)
    e.grid(row=row, column=col)
```

calling it:

```
entry_boxes(self,6,1,'N/A','self.systest',self.frame1)
```

This will be part of a class, so i need the variables to be callable from anywhere in it.

Comment: When I try to call the variable `self.systest` later in the code, it says "app instance has no attribute 'systest'"

Comment: You're basically trying to set a variable by passing a string, if I'm understanding this. While it's possible, why not create a `dict` of `Entry` variables and values, then loop through it to make the entry fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying something like this?

```
from Tkinter import StringVar,Entry,Tk
class UIclass():
    def __init__(self,root):
        #define self.frame1
        self.myfunc()

    def myfunc(self):
        self.entry_boxes(6,1,'N/A','self.systest',self.frame1)
        self.entry_boxes(6,2,'N/A','self.systest',self.frame1)
        ...
        ...
        ...

    def entry_boxes(self, row, col, default, var, frame):
        setattr(self, var, StringVar)
        setattr(self, var, default)
        e = Entry(frame, textvariable=var)
        e.grid(row=row, column=col)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    UIclass(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

If not,kindly do tell me so that I can delete this answer

Comment: Does this actually work? I am pretty sure that function doesn't work, that's what i need to fix. I have the 'UIclass' working, I just didn't include it in my question.

Comment: Well this was working....i checked it first & then posted it here...just instead of `self.frame1` i was using `root`

Comment: Thanks, i ended up not needing this at all, but it was still good to figure it out.